# Julia: Taking Runtime Input in Pluto

Tags: julia

I have written following code in Pluto notebook

```
begin
    function newton_sqrt(x,error_margin)
        a=x/2
        e=abs(a-x/a)
        while e>error_margin
            a=(a+x/a)/2
            e=abs(a-x/a)        
        end 
        println(a)  
    end
    print("Input an integer: ")
    x = BigFloat(readline())
    newton_sqrt(x,0.0001)
end
```

I am getting an error "ArgumentError: cannot parse "" as BigFloat". I am unable to take input from the Prompt.

Any help is deeply acknowledged.

Comment: `readline` (by design) doesn't work with Pluto (stdin/stdout aren't forwarded to your browser). Any reason you can't use a cell as your input?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you should use code  such as this one (I am separating Pluto cells by `##`):

```
using PlutoUI
##
@bind s TextField()
##
res = (s=="" ? "" : sqrt(BigFloat(s)))
##
md"The values of s is $s and the value of res is $res"
```

[image]